# Show loading spinner for async Vue 2 components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fairly heavy component which I would like to load asynchronously, while at the same time showing the user a loading spinner when it's loading.

This is my first attempt, using `loading` defined in `data` linked to a spinner component with `v-if="loading"`. Unfortunately this doesn't work because it seems that Vue doesn't rebind `this` properly for functions inside `components` -

```
export default {
  data: {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },

  components: {
    // ... 
    ExampleComponent: (resolve) => {
      // Doesn't work - 'this' is undefined here 
      this.loading = true;
      require(['./ExampleComponent'], (component) => {
        this.loading = false;
        resolve(component);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

I've also found some Vue 1.0 examples, but they depended on `$refs` - in 2.0 `$refs` is no longer reactive, and cannot be used for this. The only way left is for the child component itself to do something on its mount lifecycle event to the application data state to remove the loading spinner, but that seems a bit heavy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a variable outside the object scope (but still is within module scope) then use the `created` hook to attach `this`. So your updated code would look like:

```
let vm = {}

export default {
  // add this hook
  created () {
    vm = this;
  },

  data: {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },

  components: {
    // ... 
    ExampleComponent: (resolve) => {
      // since 'this' doesn't work, we reference outside 'vm'
      vm.loading = true;
      require(['./ExampleComponent'], (component) => {
        vm.loading = false;
        resolve(component);
      });
    },
  },
};
```